# Generic implementation for std::ops on tuples

Tags: generics, rust

I want to `Add` and `Sub` on a tuple. The simple implementation doesn't seem to work.

```rust
impl Add for (u32, u32) {
    type Output = (u32, u32);
    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self::Output {
        (self.0 + other.0, self.1 + other.1)
    }
}
```

It would be a lot of boilerplate to do this for every primitive. How could I do this with generics and write one implementation for every primitive (or other object) that already implements `std::ops::Add`

Answer (score 2):

Rust doesn’t allow you to create your own operators or overload arbitrary operators. But you can overload the operations and corresponding traits listed in std::ops by implementing the traits associated with the operator.

Only traits defined in the **current crate** can be implemented for arbitrary types.

So my solution is to use tuple struct `struct My2<T>(T, T);`:

```
use std::ops::Add;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct My2<T>(T, T);

impl<T: Add<Output = T>> Add for My2<T> {
    type Output = Self;

    fn add(self, other: Self) -> Self::Output {
        Self(self.0 + other.0, self.1 + other.1)
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(My2(1, 0) + My2(2, 3), My2(3, 3));
}
```

Comment: Are you saying it is not possible without implementing a new struct? The preferred solution would be implementing it that I could do `let sumed_tup = tup_a + tup_b` where the tuples are like `let tup_a = (1, 1)`. Otherwise I probably just do it manually since adding a new struct seems like unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Yes, only **types** from inside the **current crate**.